# Shared array multiprocessing Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I am running a multi-process code in Python with a shared array. The problem is that I can't initialise that array...
To share an array in a multi-process program I have read I need to use multiprocessing.Array, but when I try it as in the code below it is not printing anything + I don't have error messages.

```
import multiprocessing
...
...

if  __name__ == "__main__":

   an_array= multiprocessing.Array("i", [1,2])

   print(an_array)       # why does it not print anything? I was expecting to print [1,2]

   p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function1, args = [an_array, 3]
```

Comment: Which python version are you using ? Also, i can't reproduce this behaviour and your code will not print [1, 2] but i'll print  anothing thing.

Comment: Can you turn this into a short working example?

Comment: After fixing the syntax errors your code prints `<SynchronizedArray wrapper for <multiprocessing.sharedctypes.c_int_Array_2 object at 0x7f7bbc63df28>>`. I am running Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you include your operating system and how you run this code (eg, command line, jupyter, etc...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print elements inside the `Array` do the following:

```py
import multiprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__':

    an_array = multiprocessing.Array("i", [1, 2])

    # first choice to print element in Array:
    for element in an_array:
        print(element)

    # second choice to print elements in Array:
    print(an_array[:])

    # third choice to print elements in Array:
    print(list(an_array[:]))
```